# Why hyphen not supported in php?

Tags: php

I m going through one my GitHub project
During that I found that hp does support hyphen/dash (-) in variable name.

```
 $var-a=2;
```

Can any one tell me why?
Is this because it is an arithmetic operator?
And is their any other symbol does not supported by php?

Comment: Valid variable name: `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`

Comment: PHP has to be [one of the most documented languages](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) in use so a) check the PHP documentation, and b) why would you want to use a hyphen in the name? just accept that it is what it is.

Comment: It is not a valid variable name because that is how they decided it in the PHP source code

Comment: But rejoice, `$ಠ_ಠ =2` is perfectly valid!

Comment: Many languages don't allow the hyphen in variable names. `...notably languages in the C and Pascal families, used the hyphen for the subtraction infix operator, and did not wish to require spaces around it (as free-form languages), preventing its use in identifiers.` -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about why PHP is implemented the way it is

Comment: If its a stupid question, Yes I know it is? Though why there are 3 answers and 3 upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

That is because hyphens are same as minus sign.

**Let's take a scenario:**

```
<?php
define('name', 2);
$var = 5;

# Now when you write those combined.
$var-name; # This is actually $var minus name which is a constant.

# Same format as $var1-$var2. Except for this case there is a constant in place of $var2.
?>
```

This is the main reason for not having hyphens in a variable.

Answer (score 4):

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus:
>   `'[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

> Reasons for using a naming convention (as opposed to allowing programmers to choose any character sequence) include the following:
>
> - to reduce the effort needed to read and understand source code
> - to enable code reviews to focus on more important issues than arguing over syntax and naming standards.
> - to enable code quality review tools to focus their reporting mainly on significant issues other than syntax and style preferences.
> - to enhance source code appearance (for example, by disallowing overly long names or unclear abbreviations).

*([Wikipedia: Naming Conventions - Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)))*